# HTML5 Boilerplate and 1140px Grid... will they work together?

Tags: html, boilerplate

I'm quite a noob when it comes to html5 boilerplate, just need a quick answer: is it possible to integrate 1140px grid from cssgrid.net with HTML5 boilerplate?

Anybody tried it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just smush em together

and kinda do what it says on http://html5boilerplate.com/docs/#960.gs but with 1140.

You'll figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is for 960 http://html5boilerplate.com/docs/#960.gs